# Playwright + Cucumber - Assertions

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, cucumber, playwright, assertion

I am using playwright and Cucumber.js writing in TS.

I noticed that many features of native assertions doesn't work - especially custom message, but also soft assertions, when used together wieth cucumber.js

Is there any walkaround, or should I use say chai assertions (I really miss custom error message)?
Playwright native assertions however offer unique auto-waiting, which is nice.
Or perhaps should I write my own assertions, using promises. like this one, which I am already using:

```js
    public static waitForPooling(
        condition: boolean,
        timeout: number = settings.std_timeout,
        interval: number = settings.interval_timeout,
        errMsg: string = ''
    ): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let isSettled = false;
            const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
                if (condition && !isSettled) {
                    isSettled = true;
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    resolve();
                }
            }, interval);
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (!isSettled) {
                    isSettled = true;
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    const message = errMsg === '' ? `Timeout after ${timeout}ms` : errMsg;
                    reject(new Error(message));
                }
            }, timeout);
        });
    }
```

(But even in this case, I am not sure if this error message is always properly shown).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple workaround for playwright native web assertions using xpath/css based locators like below:

```
Let locator = page.locator("//h4/a[contains(text(),'Welcome Test User')]")
```

Or more generic:

```
Let locator =  page.locator("//h4/a[contains(.,'Welcome Test User')]")
```

And then use as below using [waitFor](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-wait-for):

Thanks to playwright [auto-waiting](https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability) :)

```
await locator.waitFor({timeout:3000});
```

This will auto- wait for the selector and indirectly verify the text as well similar like web asserions like one example below:

```
const locator = page.locator('.title');
await expect(locator).toHaveText(/Welcome Test User/);
await expect(locator).toHaveText(/Welcome  .*/);
```